# How to highlight the closing div in editplus when I click or select an opening div

Tags: javascript, html, editor, text-editor, editplus

Is there any feature on editplus to highlight the closing div when I select the opening div. 
I know it happens with the opening and closing braces in edit plus, but It would be better if the same could be done with div.

Comment: I'm not sure you can find the closing or opening div by click `ctrl + }` or  `ctrl + {` when your cursor on the opening or closing div.

Comment: Thanks a lot pal. It worked. Just keeping the cursor at the beginning or end  of opening or closing div and pressing ctrl+{ finds the corresponding closing or opening div.

Comment: This shortcut key of editplus is awesome. Didn't find it anywhere else before.

Comment: Nope i used Edit plus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the closing or opening div by click `ctrl + {` when your cursor on the opening or closing div. `ctrl + }` for curly braces such javascript or PHP coding.